# Sci-Fi TV Series identification from 90's, set on a starship, with a man who is half machine

Tags: story-identification, cyborg

As a kid in 1993-1994, I watched some kind of Sci-Fi TV series about a guy who was turned into a machine. Or at least half of him was entirely a machine and the other was human, split vertically. I remember there was some kind of conflict between machines or a machine-like race and the protagonists of this series, which ended up with him turning into a half machine. Also, I remember the woman that loved that guy when saw him turned into a half robot/half man was shocked but touched his human side on a cheek and cried or something like that. It was a dramatic scene which was memorable. I don't remember anything else beside that and that the whole setting of series was on some kind of starship.

Also, not sure but I think series was produced by Disney, although I might be mistaken. And I think it was a miniseries, as the entire show was 6 episodes, each 45-60 minutes long.

Comment: You don't mean Farscape do you? Only reason I ask is because there was a guy who was also a machine along with it taking place mostly on a ship and it had puppets making it feel kind of like Disney.

Comment: Actually, if it weren't for the Starship, it would make me think of a slightly mis-remembered [Automan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automan).

Comment: @Des, I don't think there is a man-machine character in Farscape (there is one with a metal mask who might look a little robot-ish, though).

Comment: Possibly [Babylon 5, S1, E04, *Infection?*](http://babylon5.wikia.com/wiki/Infection) That's the one where the alien artifact takes a guy over.

Comment: @K-H-W Pfff, in that case there are so many series that fit. How about _[The Six Million Dollar Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Six_Million_Dollar_Man)_.

Comment: left half machine (like terminator entirely). I also remembered that general story was war between machines and human. But it was not Terminator related as setting was on starship in the future

Comment: I've suddenly got a brainwave. Are you talking about [this](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Locutus_of_Borg)? Starship, check. Man being turned into a machine, check. Aired in the 90s, check. No Disney though.

Comment: No definitely not, I've seen Star Trek and it's not that. His body was like half machine  half human literaly, like somebody cut him verticly in half by center and patched his other half to same kind of half only machine

Comment: @MrLister - Kind of; but the date and the Disney feel (remember auto-man's graphics?) made me think Automan :)

Comment: It's not Automan thou :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible this is *[Earth Star Voyager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Star_Voyager)*? It was a television movie shown on the *Wonderful World of Disney* in 1988 as a two part pilot. It has a man who has been converted to a cyborg, Shell, with his face roughly split in half and mechanical augmentations down one side. The action is largely set on first the *Vanguard Explorer*, then the *Earth*Star Voyager*. And Dr. Arthur does have an emotional moment with Shell, although I don't see any face-touching and she did not know him from before then.

[image: Shell face view]

However, it was only aired in two parts originally (four parts in a Russian broadcast), is about as half as long as you're thinking at a total of 192 minutes, and the cyborg was created by the "Outlaw Technology Zone", a group of criminals, not a group of machine aliens.

Here is the German VHS release cover with a better look at Shell:

[image: German VHS cover]

As noted the other times this has come up, the movie is available online:

Comment: This is it, thank you very much!